# JQDateRangeSlider change default values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new in JQDateRangeSlider and I'm using it as a time slider: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dana15/LJrYf/152/)

I've used:

```
$("#slider").dateRangeSlider({defaultValues:{ min:new Date("2016-01-05T03:00:00Z"), max:new Date("2016-01-05T20:00:00Z") } });
```

to change the default values when the user presses the 'Change' button but it doesn't happen anything.

Can the default values can be changed using this instruction?

Comment: I tired with your values and it's working for me what is the issue? check http://jsfiddle.net/LJrYf/153/

Comment: I want to change that values on button click - 'Change' button

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: I hope this time answer will help you

Answer (score 0):

Please check the  below code values are changing now on click of change button

I just provided a sample one you can update code as per your requirement

```
$('#btn3').on('click', function(e) {

    $("#slider").dateRangeSlider({
    bounds: {
        "min": min3,
        "max": max3
    },
    range: {
        min: {
            minutes: 1
        }
    },
    defaultValues: {
        min: min3,
        max: max3
    }
    });
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LJrYf/154/